# Can I import .js file contents (or code) to mdx in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-component

Just like mdx documents can be imported in mdx. How can I do similar thing like importing code from a .js file and display it in `<code>` tag in .mdx file?

Comment: Yes, you can import in the same way you import in Js files.

Comment: @OscarVelandia I did that I got expected result in development environment (gatsby develop). But I am getting some weird result in production environment (gatsby build)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For use to be able to help, please edit your question and explain what you've tried, and what error messages you're getting.